# Microsoft Graph - Assign manager to user

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I am having some issues when trying to assign a manager to a user, in the response I got a *204 - No Content* but the manager object on the user is null.

The code to assign a manager in my solution (Both user and manager are objects with property id of type string which I've assigned values in a earlier stage):

```
GraphServiceClient client= new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );
await client.Users[user.Id].Manager.Reference.Request().PutResponseAsync(manager.Id);
```

How to do it according to the docs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-manager?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp):

```
   GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

   await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].Manager.Reference.Request()
  .PutAsync("6ea91a8d-e32e-41a1-b7bd-d2d185eed0e0");
```

Update:
The answer can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/915600/microsoft-graph-not-able-to-assign-manager-to-a-us.html?childToView=916006#answer-916006

Comment: Could you please provide the complete error  ,after using graphClient.Users[] ,is it started working ?

Comment: Could you please try to run Get https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/manager in graph explore and let us know if are you able to get the mangers details in response . Thanks

Comment: The questions has been answered in another forum, thank you vicky being active on this one